# PHP 5 Handler - suphp and dso issue

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I have problem where i dont know what to do get this working,

I have my own VPS server, i am in control of the PHP Handler however my problem is if i turn the

```
**PHP DSO handler**  some websites starts working but some stop working
```

alternatively if i select

```
**PHP 5 Handler suphp** some websites starts working but some stop working
```

i dont know what should i do to

```
1. convert them to working in SuPHP (as i heard this is the safest) ?
2. run both in domain wise (may be adding it to the .htacess) ?
3. any other alternatives for this type of problem ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - suPHP is the safer option because it runs scripts under their respective users, not `nobody` or `apache` making usage trackable.
2. While this may be possible, it would make it very difficult to maintain in the long run. Why not just switch to suPHP completely?
3. Look at the logs, there are only a few incompatibilities with suPHP coming from DSO. From the top of my head:

   - suPHP won't accept files CHMOD'd 0777 (or 0775), you must reduce them to 0755 at the most
   - suPHP doesn't accept the `php_admin_flag` or `php_flag` directives in `.htaccess`. You just need to create a custom `php.ini` file in the same directory with the directives you want to override.

It won't take you long to track down each problem, just look at `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` or `/var/log/apache or httpd/error_log` depending on your installation.